# Using Json.Net Schema Validation with Multiple Levels of Sub-Schema References

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I have a Json Schema that has a relative file reference, like this:

```
{
"$id": "TestPacket",
"title": "TestPacket",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "Header": {
        "$ref": "../../TestSchema/Test/TestHeader.json#"
    },
    "Body": {
        "$ref": "../../TestSchema/Test/Test.json#"
    }
}
```

Test.json also has a relative file reference:

```
{
"$id": "Test",
"title": "Test",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "Group": {
        "title": "Group",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Child": {
        "$ref": "../../TestSchema/Test/Child.json#"
    }
},
"required": [
    "Version",
    "Group"
]}
```

Both Quicktype and XMLSpy are able to successfully parse this (I have tried many, many different methods beyond the "../../folder/folder" pattern, and this works best for what we're going for).

My problem arises when I try to use Json.Net Schema Validation.  Currently, we are embedding the json into the assembly and using a JSchemaPreloadedResolver to resolve them, like this:

```
JSchemaPreloadedResolver resolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver();
resolver.Add(new Uri(TestSchema/Test/Test.json", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SchemaTests.TestSchema.Test.Test.json"));
resolver.Add(new Uri(TestSchema/Test/Child.json", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SchemaTests.TestSchema.Test.Child.json"));
resolver.Add(new Uri(TestSchema/Test/TestPacket.json", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SchemaTests.TestSchema.Test.TestPacket.json"));    resolver.Add(new Uri(TestSchema/Test/TestHeader.json", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SchemaTests.TestSchema.Test.TestHeader.json"));
```

When I load a JSchema from a JsonReader using this resolver, it works great, as long as there is no 2nd sub-schema reference.  In fact, in this example, the TestHeader.json parses, but it fails when it comes to the Test.json.  If I include Child into Test.json as a definition instead of a relative reference, it also passes.

I had a similar problem using JSchemaReaderSettings with BaseUri set to the root folder.  I eventually realized that it would successfully resolve the first reference, but then the BaseUri would be moved to the Test.Json location when trying to resolve the 2nd reference. 
I doubt that's the problem here as Add() simply adds the reference string and stream to a dictionary for lookup. It looks like to me that it shouldn't matter what is in the resolver URI and the schema $ref URI as long as they match.

My problem always occurs when I attempt to resolve the reference of a schema that is itself referenced.  Any advice?

Comment: Are you unwilling to try using a different $id and $ref reference URI? If so, I cannot help you.

Comment: I'm willing to try anything.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Just to be sure, in your example code, it looks like you're missing a double quote where you're adding new resolver schemas...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  According to [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html):

> The $id property is a URI that serves two purposes:
>   1) It declares a unique identifier for the schema.
>   2)It declares a base URI against which $ref URIs are resolved.

Because I had an $id property in my sub-schemas (Test.json), it was changing the base URI to that location when it was parsed.  This caused the next reference in the sub-schema to be incorrect.

When I remove the $id property in all schemas except the top-level schema, all schema now parse correctly.